# Animation support for Android SDK 1.5?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add some animations to my application. I've essentially got a few menu screens, that all eventually lead to the main application that is a surface view. I want to add some nice animations between screen like fading in and out between screens. What's the easiest way to do this that is supported by SDK1.5 and above (I want to target most users)?

I'm confused by what is and isn't supported in SDK1.5. My belief at the moment is that animations between different activities is not supported in 1.5 but animations in things like ViewFlipper are. It seems the easiest way is to set up a ViewFlipper, put each of my screens in that, set the animation settings and then use this to get nice transitions.

Also, is there a way to override the "no animations" setting that can be found in the phone's main settings screen under display? I'm making a game, so presentation is important, so I want to be sure that whatever I use will cause an animation regardless of this global setting.

Answer (score 0):

> My belief at the moment is that
>   animations between different
>   activities is not supported in 1.5 but
>   animations in things like ViewFlipper
>   are.

Correct.

> It seems the easiest way is to set up
>   a ViewFlipper, put each of my screens
>   in that, set the animation settings
>   and then use this to get nice
>   transitions.

Either that or just directly apply `AlphaAnimation` and kin to your `Views`.

> is there a way to override the "no
>   animations" setting that can be found
>   in the phone's main settings screen
>   under display?

No, but bear in mind that is only for inter-activity animations.

> I'm making a game, so presentation is
>   important, so I want to be sure that
>   whatever I use will cause an animation
>   regardless of this global setting.

Then do not rely upon global settings. Which, in this case, means do not rely upon inter-activity animations.